# Blank xml is being generated as a junit report using Cucumber.Options

Tags: java, xml, junit, cucumber, cucumber-junit

a Blank XML is being generated when im using the following code :

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = "junit:target/cucumber-report.xml")
public class RunCukesTest {
}
```

I'm using cucumber version 1.2.4. Is there some error in the code, or there is some version issue. as it was working with 1.2.5 but as soon as integrated with ivy it stopped generating. Is there any other jar to add in code for this.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think there is a problem with Cucumber when it worked before you added another tool to your tool chain? Look for problems around the new tool you added.

But before you do that, revert your changes until it starts working again. Then add whatever you need in small steps and always keep the solution working. I.e. run often and see that the report you are expecting still appears and contains the expected values. Commit your code between each working step and revert when something unexpected happens that breaks your functionality.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was generated due to usuage of logback-classic jar. When i  replaced logback-classic jar to logback-core jar , the issue was resolved.